# Is possible to set the TextRenderingHint to be used for a whole application?

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts

I wanto to use antialiased fonts in a C# application. I have read [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/2D-Graphics/SmoothingFonts.htm) how can be done with the Paint event of each form:

```
public class SmoothingFonts : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    ...

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        ...

        this.Paint += this.SmoothingFonts_Paint;
    }

    private void SmoothingFonts_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Font TextFont = new Font("Verdana", 25, FontStyle.Italic);
        e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Sample Text", TextFont, Brushes.Black, 20, 150);
    }
}
```

This could get cumbersome because we already have many forms done. Also, in every form we use several forms types. Can the setting for `TextRenderingHint` be set globally?

---

**EDIT 1**

The example cited, eventhough it's outdated as correctly pointed by [nobugz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236371/is-possible-to-set-the-textrenderinghint-to-be-used-for-a-whole-application/2236645#2236645), helped me to realise that the best `TextRenderingHint` to be used in this system is `AntiAliasGridFit`. The hardware platform is closed, so I can assure that it is the best configuration for this system will be the best for all the systems where the application will be deployed.

Can I set the default setting for the `TextRenderingHint` anywhere? I'm running the application in a Windows Embedded Standard (former Windows XP Embedded) image.

---

**EDIT 2**

I found that in a XP system you can set the type of `TextRenderingHint` used by the default by the registry. It is not a *by application* method, but a *by user* method. The registry keys are:

```
HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\FontSmoothing      {2 for activating font smoothing}
HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\FontSmoothingType  {1 for Antialiasing, 2 for ClearType}
```

Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article you linked manages to be both irrelevant and outdated.  ClearTypeGridFit is already the default anti-aliasing drawing mode on machines that have ClearType enabled.  And you should use the TextRenderer class for text rendering, Graphics.DrawString() has problems.

You can double-check that you are getting ClearType anti-aliasing by using SysInternals' ZoomIt utility.  You should be able to see the reddish and bluish fringes drawn along the font outline when you zoom in.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I understand that if I manage to set up ClearType in my system, the fonts will display OK. Any point to do that?

Comment: Not sure, you didn't describe your operating system.  ClearType has been available for a long time, at least since XP I think.  Try superuser.com if you have questions about enabling it.

Comment: How would I set the default `TextRenderHint` to `AntiAliasGridFit`?

Comment: The default is an operating system setting.  You'd have to use the Display control panel applet and disable ClearType.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GDI text rendering using [TextRenderer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ftkekek.aspx) if not printing it later. Other wise just right a similar class with a DrawText method with take Graphics as parameter and sets rendering hint everytime it is called

```
  TextRenderer.DrawText(    e.Graphics,
                            "Text",
                            font,
                            textRect,
                            ForeColor,
                            BackColor
                            );
```

Comment: This is to write text, but we are defining the windows forms labels with the designer. Is there an easy solution for using both?

Comment: You should enable ClearType fonts on you computer that will improve string drawing all over system. Its available in desktop properties "Advance Effects" i think on xp. Basically TextRenderer uses GDI+ text rendering and normal e.Graphics.DrawString uses system render.